# Can't log into wp-admin after migration from localhost to server

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error, migration

I'm working on WordPress website locally and I'm using Git. I followed this tutorial http://www.designcollective.io/blogs/manage-wordpress-with-git and everything works fine on localhost. I moved my website to server, changed database name etc. And homepage works fine but I can't log into wp-admin. It gives me this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Same goes for any other page except homepage. I checked database, wp-config, permissions of folders. Only thing diffrent from normal wordpress installation is that I have wp-content outside of wordpress folder same with wp-config but I point it out in index.php the way it's described in tutorial.

Any sugestions? Can't modify httpd.conf as I'm on shared hosting.

That's my .htacess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And that's my directory

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to solve the problem on my own. I changed structure to typical wordpress installation but it didn't help. So I deleted wordpress, cleaned database, installed wordpress again and manually moved my theme to Wordpress. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your directory and your `.htaccess` file ?
To be honest, moving the wp-config.php outside of WordPress directory is a good thing, but for wp-content, it's not in my opinion.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Can you access to yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-admin or yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php ?

Comment: Nope, both returns the same error I put in question. "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."

Comment: If I understand, you have change the index.php to
`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: Yes, I have it in index.php:

Comment: Have you try to add an index.php with juste an `echo 'test';` in your wordpress folder ?

Comment: Tried it now, it didn't echoed 'test' anywhere.